# Cases added with Prefix as "RE".How to display them in a while Statement

Tags: dml

We do get case added with the Prefix as  " RE "  or "FW "So we give them  in a while stmt ,as :

while(c.Subject.startsWith('RE:') || c.Subject.startsWith('FW:'))

Similarly case added with the Prefix as  " RE " or "Re"  or "FW "or "Fw" .So how can we displaythem in a while stmt ,Something like this

while(c.Subject.startsWith('RE:') || c.Subject.startsWith('Re:')  || c.Subject.startsWith('FW:') || c.Subject.startsWith('Fw:')) or do we have an format for this.

Any Suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try using the startsWithIgnoreCase, example from [docs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_startsWithIgnoreCase).

> startsWithIgnoreCase(String)
>
> Returns true if the current String begins with the specified prefix
>   regardless of the prefix case. Signature public Boolean
>   startsWithIgnoreCase(String prefix)
>
> Parameters prefix Type: String Return Value Type: Boolean
>
> Example String s1 = 'AE86 vs EK9';
>   System.assert(s1.startsWithIgnoreCase('ae86'));